# How insert data from a room table to another in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app that fetch data from an api and after that save it to a RoomDatabase(RoomTable).

I display this data with recyclerview in my main screen .

As I said my products are in a model room Table in the database (RoomTable is the name of this table ) , so How can I insert my product to another table in the roomdatabase in this case (CartTAble) after the add button of each product is clicked ?

I hope could've described clearly this .
thank's to you .

Tables :

```
@entity
class RoomTable (
  
  @primarykey
  autoincrement = true
  val id : Int 
  val title : String 


@entity
  class CartTAble (
  
  @primarykey
  autoincrement = true
  val id : Int 
  val title : String 

)
```

DAO

```
@Insert(replace strategy)
fun insertToCart(model : List<CartTable)
```

I also have repository and viewmodel but ignore for simplicity .

```
adapter :
```

```
class Myadapter (myproduct : List<RoomTAble> ) : Recycerlview.Adapter<Myadapter.Viewholder>(){

 val viewmodel : Viewmodelroom()

class Viewholder (view : View ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(){

    val title =  view.findviewbyid(R.id.sometihng)
    val image = view.finviewbyid(R.id.Someimage)

}

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {


        val layoutview =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutview)

    }


 override fun getItemCount(): Int = myproduct.size


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        val products = myproduct[position]


        holder.title.text = products.title
        Picasso.get().load(products.image).into(holder.imageproduct)


        holder.btn_add_product.setOnClickListener {

            viewModel.insertToCart()

   // in here for insertTocart paramter it need list<CArtTAble> but we have just list of RoomTAble
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your naming convention is wrong. RoomTable and CartTable are note Tables, they are Models or Entitys.

Second. Just create a CartTable with the data from RoomTable.

```
val modelCart = CartTable(title = products.title)
```

You can also simply insert only 1 model too. Simply add.

```
@Insert(replace strategy)
fun insertCart(model: CartTable)
```

Then just save it into the DB.

Comment: thank's for your help . it does work . is this the best way or is there somthing esle ?

Comment: It is the simplest way.